# TypeScript/React: Defining state outside or inside a class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When reading up on react patterns with typescripts, I am seeing two common ways to define the "state" of a React component:

Method 1.

```
interface IMyState {
  field: string;
}

class Class1 extends React.Component<object, IMyState> {
  public state: Readonly<IMyState> = {
    field: ""
  }
  // class methods...
}
```

Method 2.

```
const initialState = { field: "" }
type State = Readonly<typeof initialState>

class Class2 extends React.Component<object, State> {
  // class methods...
}
```

Both methods work, but I'm unclear on if there is a functional difference between the two patterns. My guess would be that method 2 makes it harder for someone using your class component to redefine the state, but it also seems like the type of the state is going to be less clear to the reader since it is inferred and not defined. Is there a situation where Method 2 allows you to do something that method 1 does not?

Comment: Method2 will only create a single object for the initial state, which may unwittingly be modified. In Method 1 since `state` is an instance field the object  will bre created each time you create a new instance and no one can change the initial state ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm aware that "readonly" has no power in actual javascript, but would that label at least generate a linting error for a developer who was working on this component if they tried to modify the state? I got method 2 from [this guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/ultimate-react-component-patterns-with-typescript-2-8-82990c516935) which seemed comprehensive and well done, so if its truly that dangerous why would they suggest it?

Comment: The `const` is pretty weak here, it just prevents the modification of the reference, not the fields.  inside the reference. I'm not saying it's a huge danger .. just a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people will tell you that an approach like the second solution is better.

```
type State = typeof initialState;
const initialState = Object.freeze({field: ""});
class Class2 extends Component<object, State> {
  readonly state = initialState
}
```

Why ?

1. Type information is always synced with implementation as source of truth is only one thing => the implementation
2. less type boilerplate
3. More readable (can be debate)
4. By adding readonly modifier and freezing the object, any mutation within your component will immediately end with compile error, which will prevent any runtime error.

But of course other will tel you otherwise for other good reasons.

My answer is an extract from this blog post [10++ TypeScript Pro tips/patterns with (or without) React](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/10-typescript-pro-tips-patterns-with-or-without-react-5799488d6680)